# Conditional getInitialState- if value null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having some trouble with getInitialState in react. I have some data that arrives in my props, but it will not always have the key "text".

I want it to just give it an empty value if it doesn't find the props field "text"

I basically want to say
`this.props.photo.info[0].text OR if that doesn't exist, show ''

I tried this with

The below gives an invalid props error:

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
value: ((this.props.photo && this.props.photo.info && this.props.photo.info[0].text) || '')
```

This gave the same error:

```
value:this.props.photo.info[0].text || 'empty'
```

If I do the below, all that gets returned is `[Object, Object]` which makes me think it is returning the value from the first this.props.photo or .info (ie not all the way to info[0].text)

```
(this.props.photo || this.props.photo.info || this.props.photo.info[0])
```

This is a sample of my json data in the props

```
   {
        "title": "Item 1",
        "info": [
            {
                "text": "<h1> I'm a real value </h1> <br/> <p> Not always here</p>",
            }
        ],
    },
   {
        "title": "Item 2",
        "info": [],
    },
```

Comment: where do you see [Object, Object]? is that what is rendered in the dom? if so can you post the actual render method.

Comment: [Object, Object] was returned inside my actual item `<h1> this.props.value </h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see why your second example would be [Object Object] but the first one looks like it should work to me, but you will get an error if there is no `info[0]`. Try the following? -

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
    value: ((this.props.photo && this.props.photo.info && this.props.photo.info[0] && this.props.photo.info[0].text) || '')
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I often use [default values](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/11/react-v0-4-prop-validation-and-default-values.html#default-values), they can provide default values in a very elegant way.

Comment: This does not work. As i my example, using default props like that gives me a invalid props error